# How can I find help for new Ubuntu users?

Tags: documentation

I've just started using Lubuntu. It's the first time I've ever used Linux.

Can any of you send me a tutorial-video for new users or explain the basics to me?

Comment: Ubuntu has an official tutorial to [Install Ubuntu Desktop](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop).  The only thing it does not include is how to configure your motherboard to boot installation media. For that you will need to follow the instructions on your vendor boot splash and find options for boot priority, or read the documentation for your motherboard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a quick and easy guide, click on the top left corner and then type `help`<kbd>Enter</kbd> and click the icon.

[image]

For a more comprehensive guide, *Getting Started with Ubuntu* is one for the Ubuntu operating system. It is written under an open source license and is free for you to download, read, modify and share.

The manual will help you become familiar with everyday tasks such as surfing the web, listening to music and scanning documents. With an emphasis on easy to follow instructions, it is suitable for all levels of experience.

- Read online [Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop: Applications and Administration](https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/6guUEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PP1)
- Download the Spanish language version of Getting Started with Ubuntu 13.10, *[Primeros pasos con Ubuntu 13.10](https://ubuntu-manual.org//download/13.10/es/screen)* (155 pages, PDF).
- [Guia Basica de Ubuntu](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513185416/https://vivaubuntu.com/) - 18.04, 20.04
- [¿Cómo instalar Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS?](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507001654/https://rescalante.com/blog/view/13)
- Download the English language version of [Getting Started with Ubuntu 16.04](https://files.ubuntu-manual.org/manuals/getting-started-with-ubuntu/16.04/en_US/screen/Getting%20Started%20with%20Ubuntu%2016.04.pdf)
- Download the English language version of [Getting Started with Ubuntu 14.04](https://files.ubuntu-manual.org/manuals/getting-started-with-ubuntu/14.04/en_US/screen/Getting%20Started%20with%20Ubuntu%2014.04.pdf).

#### Ubuntu Documentation

- [Ubuntu documentation for Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/)

  | Release | Desktop | Server |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat) | [HTML](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/index.html) | [HTML](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs) and [PDF](https://assets.ubuntu.com/v1/544d9904-ubuntu-server-guide-2024-01-22.pdf) |
  | Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) | [HTML](https://help.ubuntu.com/22.04/ubuntu-help/index.html) | [HTML](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs) and [PDF](https://assets.ubuntu.com/v1/544d9904-ubuntu-server-guide-2024-01-22.pdf) |
  | Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) | [HTML](https://help.ubuntu.com/20.04/ubuntu-help/index.html) | [PDF](https://web.archive.org/web/20210831221626/https://assets.ubuntu.com/v1/f954307f-ubuntu-server-guide.pdf) (Archive link) |
  | Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver) | [HTML](https://web.archive.org/web/20230601011425/https://help.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-help/index.html) (Archive link) | [PDF](https://web.archive.org/web/20230405145923/https://help.ubuntu.com/18.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf) (Archive link) |
  | Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus) | [HTML](https://web.archive.org/web/20200328220300/https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/index.html) (Archive link) | [PDF](https://web.archive.org/web/20201013123924/https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf) (Archive link) |

  Starting with 20.04, the server guide is now a common document published at https://ubuntu.com/server/docs based on [corresponding posts in Ubuntu Discourse](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-server-documentation/11322).
- [Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommunityHelpWiki) has useful wikis for new Ubuntu users.

#### Basic concepts

The same skills that Windows users learn are transferable to new Ubuntu users.

1. Don't install crap. Installing crap makes more problems than it solves. Use the default Ubuntu repositories as a source for packages to install.
2. Be zealous about not adding unnecessary PPAs to your software sources. This prevents package management issues.
3. Don't use root privileges except when required. Misusing root privileges is a major security risk.
4. Keep your system up-to-date and upgrade or reinstall the operating system when it reaches end of life.
5. Don't use weak passwords or reuse the same password in multiple websites.

Answer (score 2):

You can start with:

- [Official Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/)
- [Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommunityHelpWiki)
- [Official Ubuntu Tutorials](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/)
- [Ubuntu man-pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/)
- [Ubuntu Packages Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/)
- [Debian Administrator's Handbook](https://debian-handbook.info/get/now/) (many parts are identical to Ubuntu)

And of course you should determine which tasks you are going to solve.

Answer (score 2):

There is on-line [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/UpgradeToLubuntu) you can access for **Lubuntu**.

There are links to readable topics (with lots of images and/or animations) for common tasks:

- Browse the web
- Change the date, time and timezone
- Change the wallpaper
- Connect to online accounts
- Use the system search
- Use windows and workspaces
- Get online
- Launch applications
- Switch tasks

Comment: @muru Thanks for pointing out the **404**. A new link has been set and the answer has been shortened.

Answer (score 1):

It’s rather a general question, but I’d suggest

1. download Ubuntu from https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop
2. tutorial on how to create bootable usb here:
   https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview
3. I’d suggest set up as dual boot, or install it on an old computer so you still have a working computer you can use
4. browse questions here to get a feel for Ubuntu. Ask a question if you have problems.
5. the official Ubuntu tutorials at
   https://ubuntu.com/tutorials
   are a useful resource
6. personally I found ‘Linux command line’ by William Shotts really good for getting started on the command line. It’s free to download.
7. play - enjoy !!

My experience of transitioning from windows about 8 months ago has been really positive - initially I liked the security of having windows as an option on my computers, but in truth I now very rarely boot into windows (only for a couple of very specific things that Microsoft or Apple make impossible on Linux (specifically - accessing a shared outlook calendar, and syncing music on my iPhone). Almost everything I want to do works better in Linux than it did in windows - I had to spend a bit of effort getting to where I am, but now I’m much more in control and can do many things more efficiently.

Good luck.