# Gave up trying to recover, reinstalled - how to avoid previous problems?

Tags: login, suspend, password, laptop

Dell Latitude e6530, Xubuntu 20.04(.3?)

Thought I had recovered my password using Grub Recovery, but was unable to add a user: neither new nor either old passwords were  again accepted. Login prompt again after shutting lid and re-opening, but neither present nor either of my past passwords were accepted.

So I did a reinstall, wiping out the entire previous one, to avoid having to mess with a dual boot. Kept my original/default user type as "Custom", whatever that means. Apparently with some admin rights using sudo. Was able to create a new user as an administrator.

Did making my original user an admin cause me to get locked out of the system, i.e. new password (and old) not being accepted?

Comment: You are asking highly technical questions. Answers that are "*not in a techie way*" will be useless.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find help for new Ubuntu users?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440781/how-can-i-find-help-for-new-ubuntu-users)

Comment: Thank you for the training wheels links. I'll check them out. But I didn't find anything that addresses my more immediate issues: What caused my login password not to be accepted - making my single user an administrator when I already had (some?) admin rights (like installing programs and updates) or changing my password? Also how to disable password prompt every time the screen has gone blank. Would greatly appreciate tips for those issues. Thanks : )

Comment: If you want a qualified answer, you have to ask a qualified question .. Exact what steps did you follow that broke your system, and what steps / commands are now failing - one problem at the time, please.

Comment: @SorenA Thanks for your lightening response. My question boils down to: Does making a single user an administrator cause its password to not be accepted? Other than changing my password and setting my user to No Password on Login, that's the only significant thing I did before I had password problems. 

The issue has disappeared since the reinstall, but I'd like to avoid the same problem in the future, which is why I'd like to know the cause.