# I borrowed a Ubuntu administration book dating to 2013. Is it useless?

Tags: 12.04, server, administration

I guess the book can be partly good, and I am waiting for other Linux administration books from the library.

So, would I waste my time with that book? It talks about Ubuntu 12.04.

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and I have no idea what changes took place between 2013 and 2024.

Thanks!

Comment: Use this one https://books.google.nl/books?id=6guUEAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: It's not useless; however you'll need to have a *fair* knowledge of the system to detect what will have changed, and what won't have.  I'd expect 70% to 90% of it will apply today but if you're not familiar with GNU/Linux Servers you may not detect in the first paragraph of a chapter if it'll apply or not (*I have my books from that era, and usually the title of the chapter + first paragraph tells you if you can keep reading or need to skip the chapter*)

Comment: Almost no technical IT book (programming, sysops, what have you) older than ten years is worth reading, unless you're planning to maintain old systems. I'm sure there are exceptions but they are few.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find help for new Ubuntu users?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440781/how-can-i-find-help-for-new-ubuntu-users) - Ubuntu Server Guide was last updated in January, 2024. See link in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Most changes were in the GUI. GNOME 2 desktop has been replaced by Unity (that has been used in 12.04) and later by GNOME 3. You tagged your question "server", so I guess you don't have a GUI, so this will not apply to you.

As for command line, it didn't change that much (from command line point of view, all Debian-based systems are very similar). Probably the most important changes are introduction of new `apt` command for software installation (your book will probably use `apt-get` - but `apt-get` should still work anyway) and introduction of snap applications - you won't find this in your book (but on a server, I suppose there are no snap applications installed by default, so you can ignore them for a while).

I don't know the exact contents of your book - as you didn't even mention the title - but my guess is that most of it should still be relevant.

Comment: I would say a bit more has changed since 12.04. Systemd and networking coming to mind

Comment: @mpboden Yes, you are right. I forgot about the SysV initscripts vs systemd change :(. So the book may be actually less useful than I thought.

Comment: I didn't give the book's title cause it's a French book.